# PAM with KRB5 to Active Directory - How to prevent update of AD password?

Tags: linux, active-directory, fedora, kerberos, pam

I have a working Fedora 9 system that's set up to authenticate users via PAM -> krb5 -> Active Directory.  I'm migrating this to Fedora 14, and everything works, but it's working *too* well :-)  On Fedora 9, if a Linux user updated their password, it did not propagate to their Active Directory account.  On Fedora 14, it is changing their A/D password.  The problem is I don't want A/D to be updated.  Here's my `password-auth-ac`:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_krb5.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_krb5.so
```

I tried removing the line

```
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok
```

But then when attempting to change the Linux password, if they provide their A/D password for the authentication prompt, they get the error:

```
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

What I want to achieve is:

1. Allow authentication with either the A/D or Linux password (the Linux password is a fall-back for certain sysadmin users in case A/D is unavailable for some reason).  This is working now.
2. Allow users to change their Linux passwords without affecting their A/D passwords.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> But then when attempting to change the
>   Linux password, if they provide their
>   A/D password for the authentication
>   prompt, they get the error:
>
> passwd: Authentication token
>   manipulation error

How is this a problem? If you want to update your Linux password you type in your current Linux password. Your requirement #2 is still satisfied. Do you have a 3rd requirement?

- Allow a user to change their Linux password without first entering it.

Comment: Good question -- the requirement is to allow changing the Linux password after authenticating with the A/D password.  The answer "this is not possible" is acceptable.